# How to correctly reference IHeaderDictionary?

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget

I want to use interface `IHeaderDictionary` (or the class `HeaderDictionary`) in a class library. It is an interface defined in **ASP.NET Core** which represents a collection of http request or response headers. We have some classes working with it in a separate git repository and we want to define a contract separately in a yet another separate git repository. So I have a tiny C# project and there is only a contract in it, nothing else.

The question is this: Which nuget should I reference to be able to use `IHeaderDictinary` in my contract?

MSDN says it is defined in nuget `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref`. And it is really there, but it is forbidden to reference that nuget. (It has package type DotnetPlatform which effectively prevents it to be included in regular class libraries, as mentioned in other discussions.) But which nuget should I reference if not that one? I tried to reference `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`, but it is a framework one, so it cannot be referenced too. Then we found that in an older application we used this interface from nuget called `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features`. And it works, I can still use this one but when I look to nuget gallery, I can see it is an abandoned nuget, the latest version is 6.0.0-preview, so apparently this is not the correct way how Microsoft intended us to use IHeaderDictionary.

So what am I missing here? Typically, authors of nugets provide something like "contract" or "abstractions" nugets which are tiny and can be included in other contracts. Please help me to understand what is the problem with ASP.NET and how to use it in contracts.

Comment: Hi @AI Kepp, what's the version of your class library? Do you want to use IHeaderDictionary in .NETT 7 class library? If so, just install the latest version(6.0.0-preview.4.21253.5) of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features` can work fine. You can check the framework support here:https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features/6.0.0-preview.4.21253.5#supportedframeworks-body-tab

Comment: @Rena the fact that Microsoft published preview but then did not publish the final 6.0.0  version of this nuget leads me to a conclusion that it is not recommended to use that way. Currently, we use ASP.NET Core 6.0.0, but I don't want preview libraries so I use 5.x version of this nuget.

Comment: I know this is old by now but `IHeaderDictionary` just derives from `IDictionary<string, StringValues>` so your library can take that as a parameter.